# SSRS Chart Data - Filtering options for Values?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, charts, filtering

I'm currently running Visual Studio 2010 for reporting for pharmaceutical batch production. The system creates archive data table with the following fields:

-`VARIABLE`, which is the name of the variable,

-`TIMESTAMP`, the time when the value of the variable was recorded,

-`VALUE`, the actual value of the variable at a specific timestamp,

and so on.
The dataset I'm concerned with contains 3 variables: `Level`, `BatchTimer`, and `BatchID`.

Goal: What I want to achieve is to have `Level` as the Y value, `BatchTimer` as the X-axis(Category Group), and `BatchID` as the Series Group. Therefore I tried putting the `VALUE` field for all three regions, and adding filter options for the Category Group and the Series Group. Here are the filter options I added:

[Filter Option for Category Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXkWr.png)

[Filter Option for Series Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOKzj.png)

The problem now was filtering the Y value so that it only has field `VALUE` of Variable `Level`. I then assumed I needed to add a filtering expression to the value region of the chart data, which I don't know how to.

So my question is:

1. Is this the correct way to approach my goal?
2. If so, how would I go about filtering the Y value so that it only shows a certain variable in a dataset(in my case, `Level`)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem statement correctly, Your end goal is to filter out `Level` values, i.e For Example Level has values 1,2,3..10 but you want your Level values to be let's say only 3.

So return all data where level is 3. Once you have this datset, you are already able to add `BatchTimer` as the X-axis(Category Group), and `BatchID` as the Series Group.

You need a Parameter of a Filter in your dataset something like below.

[image]

Now above way is static for Level=3.

How do we make it dynamics
We create a Parameter and ask user to give level. Then depending on this parameter value we filter dataset as below ( this should be added to dataset query)
`level` field Operator: = and value of the parameter

```
(Parameters.level.Value)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The three variables, `Level`, `BatchTimer` and `BatchID` are variables inside the dataset, not fields. The only fields I can use are `VALUE` and `VARIABLE`, which show the value and name of the variable respectively. My end goal is to apply those three variables ,that are all in one dataset, to the Y value, Category Group, and Series Group individually. Thank you for your answer, but I might not have been specific enough about my end goal.

Comment: So you mean for your Field "Variable", It will have 3 different values (Level, BatchTimer and BatchID)?
and you need your x-axis as Level, BatchTimer and BatchId as grouped.
Now on Your Y-Axis (Series Gorup) only By Level?

Comment: Yes, the field `VARIABLE` has 3 different values(Level, BatchTimer, and BatchID). I need my X-axis as BatchTimer only, and Y-axis by Level.